# About return names in functions

Tags: haskell

Why does this not work?

```
summ :: (Num a) => [a] -> Int

summ [] = 0;

summ (x:list) = x + summ list
```

Is it because it is not sure that `x + summ list` is always an Int? If `a` is `Num` isn't there made some kind of conversion ?

Comment: Indeed, you suspicion is correct: think of what would happen if we ran `summ [1.3, 2.1]`. The type signature claims this is a correct call (since doubles are `Num`s) and that the result is an `Int` -- but it's can't realistically be an integer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You make use of [**`(+) :: Num a => a -> a -> a`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.15.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:-43-) in `x + summ list`. As the type signature suggests, both operand and the result all have the same type. If you thus have a `x` of type `Num a => a`, then `summ list` also should be of the same type `a`, and not an `Int`.

You thus should work with:

```
summ :: Num a => [a] -> a
summ [] = 0
summ (x:list) = x + summ list
```

with `a` as result type. If you use a list of `Int`s as parameter, then you will retrieve an `Int` as result, and if you use a list of `Integer`s as parameter, then this will produce an `Integer`.

If you know the items of your list have a type that is a member of the [**`Integral`** typeclass](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.15.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#t:Integral), you can make useo f [**`fromIntegral :: (Integral a, Num b) => a -> b`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.15.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:fromIntegral) to convert these to an `Int`:

```
summ :: Integral a => [a] -> Int
summ [] = 0
summ (x:list) = fromIntegral x + summ list
```

but this is likely not a good idea, since of you work with an `Integer`, such numbers can get arbitrary large, and thus might result in overflow.